# Selecting Your Own Keys

Tags: wallet, address, cardano-address, public-key, private-key

Is there a way I can specify the prime number product used to generate the public private key pair - on the creation of a wallet address?

I understand that the primes in the product would have to meet certain cirtiaera but that's okay.

Comment: What do you mean with "prime number product"? Can you give more details about what you know on that?

Comment: Yeah so vitalik was talking about having two primes he can easily generate to get his key. I thought it would be a nice idea to do this instead of seed phrases and have some easy to rember way to generate the primes.

Comment: Sorry but it's been almost a year and I can't remember the details, but the primes were used for the eliptic curve encryption scheme.